# Getting "device is already associated with other accounts the Apple Developer Program or the Apple Developer Enterprise Program." message

Tags: xcode

This device is already associated with other accounts the Apple Developer Program or the Apple Developer Enterprise Program. Please use a different device.

[image]

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: Any progress or resolution?

Comment: I had the same issue. I just uninstalled the app from the iPhone and installed again. it was fixed. I can run the app perfectly fine on my iPhone now.

Comment: @AshutoshSoni which app did you uninistall?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing trying to use xcode to publish an app for a client. Apple were unclear if this was referring to my device or the customers device.

Comment: This seems to be discussed here also : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708437

Comment: Yeah. I the same app that was installed on the phone I removed it. only then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as I got a lot of client accounts connected to my Xcode accounts.

What I did is to remove some old accounts and it works. It seems Xcode has a Maximum account number that can be connected to Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I found a new way to solve this problem.
You don't have to logout any accounts on XCode.
Just create a new user of your macos and login to the new user which you created.
then open xcode, login to the developer account which you cannot login in before.